# How to play online games on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, flash, chromium

I am a fan of  8 Ball Pool on Miniclip. Also I have dual boot OSs, so I play on Windows, but whenever I open it in Ubuntu in Chromium browser, I always get a white screen like this:

[image: image of mini clip]

I even tried playing it on Facebook, but it is still like that.

I have installed Flash Player or plugin,. but I'm not sure it got installed or whatever. Can someone please tell me any way to fix it?

Comment: Not enough rep to comment, but have you restarted your browser? Might be as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

I think those are "Shockwave" games. Not Adobe Flash games. There is no "Adobe Shockwave" binary available for Linux.

http://get.adobe.com/shockwave/‎

Though you can play those games using - Wine + Windows Version of Firefox + Shockwave Player. Or perhaps you might wana try VirtualBox -> Windows XP SP3 -> Shockwave Player -> Internet Explorer 8

Comment: okay how can i get all those

Comment: Open a terminal window - (ALT+CTRL+T) : then - sudo apt-get install wine

Comment: Later download Firefox and Shockwave from Filehippo.com.

Comment: Alternatively you can install Wine and VirtualBox from Ubuntu Software Center. Better search Google for how to install Wine and VirtualBox.

Comment: but i want it on chrome is it possible